# Is it possible to notify with NotifyOSD when a specified process terminates?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, shutdown, notify-osd

I must admit being a heavy Firefox user, so when i terminate FF, i always have to check with the system monitor if it's process is really terminated before shutting down Ubuntu. Otherwise i will get a "restore session screen" on the next session due to Ubuntu forcefully terminating FF during shut-down.

So then i had the idea of monitoring FF, and when the process is terminated to send a command to NotifyOSD to, well, notify me that FF is down and it is safe to shut down Ubuntu.

As i am pretty new to Ubuntu, i have no idea how to do this, or even if it is possible... Any advice where to start?

Best regards and thanks in advance! Ruessel

PS: I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ...

Create a folder called `bin` in your home directory if such a folder doesn't already exist.

Create a plain text file in `~/bin` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if 
    pgrep firefox
then       
    notify-send  --urgency=critical "Is Firefox still running?"
else 
    notify-send  "No Firefox process is running"
    zenity --question --text="Proceed to shutdown?"
  if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
  else
    exit
  fi
fi
```

Save it as `fx-check-n-shutdown`. No need for any suffix.

Then, right-click on `fx-check-n-shutdown` from within your file manager. Select `Properties` and make the file "executable" for you.

Install `libnotify-bin` from the software center or by running `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin` in a terminal.

Once that's done, type `fx-check-n-shutdown` in your terminal and hit `enter`. You should see a notification asking you  "Is Firefox still running?" or that "No Firefox process is running".

In the latter case *where no Firefox process is running*, the notification will soon disappear by itself (provided your mouse pointer isn't over the area occupied by the notification).

You'll also see a small window asking you if you wish to shutdown or not.

If Firefox is still running, you'll need to dismiss the notification yourself by clicking on the notification and you can then ensure that you've closed Firefox thoroughly.

What you've done is to create a script called `fx-check-n-shutdown`.
You've made it executable.
You've installed `libnotify-bin` a program that allows ordinary users to make their own notifications.

What the script does:

- It checks if *any* process with "firefox" in it is running.
- If a Firefox process is running, you're notified. You can then open a terminal, and run `pgrep firefox` to get the ID of the process (PID) and use that PID to get more details of the actual command running by running `cat /proc/<pid>cmdline` where you'll use the actual PID instead of `<pid>`.
- If no process involving Firefox is open, you're briefly notified and a Zenity shutdown window opens asking you whether you really wish to shutdown or not.

Once you're satisfied, you can set up a keyboard shortcut for launching `fx-check-n-shutdown` instead of having to run it via a terminal. How you set up the shortcut depends on your particular flavor of Ubuntu. For Ubuntu 14.04, instructions are here: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html

Comment: Works like a charm, but the usability is suboptimal... I have to ddos-attack my laptop, as if FF is still running it just replies, that it is... As expected :) But thanks for the Line: `zenity --question --text="Proceed to shutdown?"` I used that in the Script proposed from Serg! Ah, and really perfect explanations about what this does! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do so. One could write a wrapper script , which will launch a process and capture its PID and monitor for that PID. For instance, I've written a small script bellow, that if called like `monitor_process.sh firefox` will launch firefox and wait till it exits.

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup $@ &> /dev/null &
PID=$!
while ps --no-headers  -p $PID > /dev/null
do
   echo $PID
   : # no-op
   sleep 0.25
done

notify-send "$@ exited"
```

Of course there may be multiple instances of firefox, so we want to have something like `monitor_process.sh firefox` and it will monitor all of the firefox windows , untill  they all exit.

```
#!/bin/bash
SELF=$$
while  pgrep -f firefox | grep -v $SELF > /dev/null
do
   : # no-op
   sleep 0.25
done

notify-send "$@ exited"
```

The way I've done it above is by getting PIDs of all processes that contain "firefox" string in them, but ignoring the PID of the script (because `monitor_process.sh firefox` will be included into the list, and we don't want that - the script wont exit if it constantly monitors itself).

Of course , the script will exit once it sends out notification and may need restart if you reopen a window after it exits, so it would probably be easier to also add `nohup $@ &> /dev/null &` to the second line in the script and use it as both launcher and monitor.

Alternatively , we could add an outer while loop that will monitor if firefox is running, and start monitoring only if its running; if not - start monitoring.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_monitoring()
{

while  pgrep -f "$@" | grep -v $SELF &> /dev/null
do
   : # no-op
   sleep 0.25
done
notify-send "$@ exited"
}

main()
{
local SELF=$$
while true
do
  pgrep -f "$@" | grep -v $SELF > /dev/null 
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && start_monitoring "$@"
sleep 0.25
done
}
main "$@"
```

And the code above will work for multiple instances of firefox and multiple closes and reopenings , so you can close firefox during the session, it will notify you, and keep on waiting till new one shows up , and will start monitoring that.

Comment: Awesome reply! I tested it in the Terminal, and it works like a charm. Would be perfect if it would give the Zenity shutdown window when notifying that FF is terminated. How could i integrate this?  Just paste the Line: `zenity --question --text="Proceed to shutdown?"` after the Line: `notify-send "$@ exited"` ?    Also, i tried to get the script started at the same time as FF. But unfortunately i failed... What i did was to add `monitor_process.sh firefox` to the firefox.desktop file, but that resulted in FF trying to open the url monitor_process.sh in a new tab...  Any ideas?

Comment: @ruessel Yes, just add the `zenity . . .` after `notify-send . . .`  As for the `firefox.desktop` , I wouldn't touch that and create separate `.desktop` file with `Exec=/full/path/to/monitor_process.sh firefox` line

Comment: Why would you separate the FF Launcher from the monitor_process.sh? `Prolly a noob question` I would like to just start FF, and not add any extra clicks...

Comment: @ruessel so if you look at the `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` there's several options that correspond to those shown in the launcher when you right click on the firefox icon there. They all call firefox with different arguments, so that means if you want to make sure *all* of them start with `monitor_process.sh` , you need to add that `monitor_process.sh` for *all* of them.  It's just easier to make separate shortcut.

Comment: Would there be a problem in running it as following? `Exec=firefox %u && /full/path/to/monitor_process.sh firefox`

Comment: @ruessel yes, it will be waiting for `firefox %U` to exit, so the script will never be called.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ; instead of &&   ...that would work though, right?   I spotted some Lines starting with Exec=    `Exec=firefox %u`  `Exec=firefox -new-window`  `Exec=firefox -private-window`  so assuming i would add `; /full/path/to/monitor_process.sh firefox` at the end of every one of these lines, in both firefox.desktop files that i have found, should that work?  PS:Thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: @ruessel no, that also won't work. `Exec=` has to have exactly one statement, no `;` is allowed. Let me think about this for a bit , I'll let you know if I come up with an idea

Comment: Whell, i tried it, but it does not work with ; as it waits for the 1st process to stop/end. Tried with & and it launches FF and then it opens a prompt asking "how to open file: monitor_process.sh" ...duh!