# Is it possible to run more than one command in a someapp.desktop file?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, .desktop

i am just trying to find a way to run an extra command when opening an app (Firefox), but i am failing miserably...

The original question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755190/is-it-possible-to-notify-with-notifyosd-when-a-specified-process-terminates).

I tried to add my command after the app command as in the following line:

```
Exec=firefox %u & /bin/monitor_process.sh firefox
```

But this results in the `monitor_process.sh` being opened by FF, showing an "open file with..." dialogue box.

I tried `;` `&` `&&` but to no avail...

So, any idea how to handle multiple commands in .desktop files?

Also, [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg) Said:

> that also won't work. Exec= has to have exactly one statement, no ; is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Desktop files are not run in a shell; that means that you can't run complex commands such as `firefox %u & /bin/monitor_process.sh firefox` directly; in that case everything fails at the `&` part, which is not intepreted as "background `firefox %u`" but literally as `&`, which is passed as an argument to `firefox %u` along with `/bin/monitor_process.sh` and `firefox`.

To fix that run `firefox %u & /bin/monitor_process.sh firefox` in a shell which at least supports job control (simply `dash` would work):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=foo
Exec=sh -c 'firefox %u & /bin/monitor_process.sh firefox'
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this Exec line for your `.desktop` file:

```
Exec= bash -c "firefox && /bin/monitor_process.sh firefox"
```

`bash` will open a shell and correctly interpret the &&.

Comment: but would that not result in FF getting launched and bash waiting for FF to terminate in order to run /bin/monitor_process.sh firefox ?  As i found somewhere: `A && B  means: Run B if A succeeded`

Comment: That works well for me.

Comment: It wont work because  bash would wait for Firefox to exit. You could run firefox in the background , by replacing the command bash runs with `firefox &; /path/to/monitor_process. sh firefox `

Comment: Well i got it working partially! instead of && i used & and everything gets started. BUT! As my script is monitoring all processes that contain the word firefox, it also monitors the bash process, and waits for it to exit aswell. So my last issue would be how to get bash excluded from being monitored.  Here is the code i used for excluding $SELF:  `while  pgrep -f "$@" | grep -v $SELF &> /dev/null` could i change it to `while  pgrep -f "$@" | grep -v $SELF; bash &> /dev/null` ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy [Why the semicolon?](https://superuser.com/a/269434/500826)